# How to save password in TortoiseHG on mac

Tags: macos, passwords, tortoisehg, mercurial-keyring

How can I use `mercurial_keyring` with TortoiseHg on mac?

Guides usually installs `mercurial_keyring` with `pip install` or `easy_install` but it doesn't work for TortoiseHG on mac.

And TortoiseHg ends up with error:

> No module named mercurial_keyring

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that TortoiseHg ignores modules installed with pip or easy_install on mac os.

Instead you have to copy **mercurial_keyring.py**, **mercurial_extension_utils.py** and **keyring** (whole keyring folder) to TortoiseHg.app contents python folder:

TortoiseHg.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/

You can do so by going to applications and *right click* on TortoiseHG.app then select *Show Package Contents*

The modules version can make difference too so make sure you pick right modules for your tortoiseHG version.

Links to modules:

- [mercurial-extension_utils](https://bitbucket.org/Mekk/mercurial-extension_utils)
- [mercurial_keyring](https://bitbucket.org/Mekk/mercurial_keyring)
- [keyring](https://github.com/jaraco/keyring)

Credit goes to "Anonymous" in [TortoiseHg mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisehg/mailman/message/35513098/)

Comment: Last link to mailing list does not seem to work, at least for me. By any chance you're referring to [this one](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/4634/mercurial-keyring-is-not-available-in)?

Comment: Updated links: https://pypi.org/project/mercurial_extension_utils/   https://pypi.org/project/mercurial_keyring/ and the two .py files need to go into TortoiseHg.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/hgext

Comment: I should add that I saw there is already a keyring folder, in TortoiseHg 5.9.1.

Comment: However I now get an error: keyring: keyring backend doesn't seem to work, password was not saved. Error details: No recommended backend was available. Install a recommended 3rd party backend package; or, install the keyrings.alt package if you want to use the non-recommended backends. See https://pypi.org/project/keyring for details.